# Git clone from Bitbucket

Tags: git

I am trying to `git clone` a repo off of bitbucket. I use `git clone {https} temp`. This gives me an error of `refs not found`. The https address is the one I get off of bitbucket, but the one they provide uses `hg` instead of `git`. Why is this happening?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to clone an hg repo with git.  You can't do that directly, though there might be some way if you search.

Comment: Who is `they`? Github surely only uses git. Which hg-address have you been provided?

Comment: I see, that's an old question. Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

@Qudit is right - you need `hg` to clone a mercurial repo, and `git` to clone a git repo. There are gateways to transmute one to another, but those are set up usually at the repository site. Solution: use mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Install hgsvn, then do this

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/"channel"/dotfiles/src dotfiles

Where channel is the users files you want to clone.